# OnEdit() vs onEdit(e) implications transition and operation with respect to different use cases

Tags: google-apps-script

I want timestamp to be populated in cell `A1` in only that sheet which is edited and not all the sheets.

Currently my code below with OnEdit() function does many things like toggling background color in a cell and hiding unhiding sheets and columns and rows, etc.

The `// Add timestamps` code block is updating every sheet with timestamp, I want timestamp updated only in sheets where edit is made.

I thought of using `onEdit(e)` trigger, but afraid it will adversely impact the working of other code blocks.

Please help how can I achieve this.

```
function installedOnEdit(){
  cpd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // The function TO HIDE/INHIDE SHEETS/TABS WHEN SELECTED FROM C OVERVIEW SHEET
  var pac = cpd.getSheetByName("2: PAC ");
  var product_Details = cpd.getSheetByName("3: Product Details");
  var op_Details = cpd.getSheetByName("4: Op Details");
  var marketplace = cpd.getSheetByName("5. Marketplace Details");
  var approvals = cpd.getSheetByName("6: Approvals");
  var product_Pricing = cpd.getSheetByName("7a: Product Pricing");
  var op_Pricing = cpd.getSheetByName("7b: O Pricing");
  var eos_EOL = cpd.getSheetByName("8: EOS/EOL");
  var c_Overview = cpd.getSheetByName("C Overview");
  var copyofprodpricing = cpd.getSheetByName("Copy of 7a: Product Pricing");

  var [cella, cellb, cellc, celld, celle, cellf, cellg, cellh, celli] = c_Overview.getRange("C6:C14").getValues().flat();
  if (cella =="Yes") { pac.showSheet(); } else { pac.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellb == "Yes") { product_Details.showSheet(); } else { product_Details.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellc == "Yes") { op_Details.showSheet(); } else { op_Details.hideSheet(); }
  if (celld == "Yes") { marketplace.showSheet(); } else { marketplace.hideSheet(); }
  if (celle == "Yes") { approvals.showSheet(); } else { approvals.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellf == "Yes") { product_Pricing.showSheet(); } else { product_Pricing.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellg == "Yes") { op_Pricing.showSheet(); } else { op_Pricing.hideSheet(); }
  if (celli == "Yes") { eos_EOL.showSheet(); } else { eos_EOL.hideSheet(); }

  // Add timestamps
  
  pac.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  product_Details.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  op_Details.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  marketplace.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  approvals.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  product_Pricing.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  op_Pricing.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  eos_EOL.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
  c_Overview.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);

  

  // Function to CAPTURE APPROVAL TIMESTAMP
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var email_check1= product_Pricing.getRange("E23");

  if (email_check1.isChecked()) {
    product_Pricing.getRange("F23").setValue(new Date());
    product_Pricing.getRange("G23").setValue(email);

  } else {
    product_Pricing.getRange("F23").clearContent();
    product_Pricing.getRange("G23").clearContent();

  }

  var email_check2= option_Pricing.getRange("D17");

  if (email_check2.isChecked()) {
    op_Pricing.getRange("E17").setValue(new Date());
    op_Pricing.getRange("F17").setValue(email);

  } else {
    op_Pricing.getRange("E17").clearContent();
    op_Pricing.getRange("F17").clearContent();

  }

  // The function for HIDE/UNHIDE ROW IN EOS/EOL sheet
  var eos = cpd.getSheetByName("8: EOS/EOL");
  var cellx = eos.getRange("D13").getValue();
  if ((cellx == "EOS") || ((cellx == ""))) { eos.hideRows(15); } else { eos.showRows(15); }



  // The function for HIDE/UNHIDE ROWS IN PAC DETAILS WHEN DIRECT IS SELECTED IN GENERAL INFO TAB
  var general_info = cpd.getSheetByName("1: General Info (Required)");
  var check = general_info.getRange("J9").getValue();
  if (check == "Direct") { pac.hideRows(37, 8); } else {
    if ((check == "Partner") || (check == "")) {
      pac.showRows(37, 8);
    }
  }

  

  // The function for HIDE/UNHIDE COLUMNS IN PRICING PAGE WHEN DIRECT IS SELECTED IN GENERAL INFO TAB
  var dirpar_check = general_info.getRange("J9").getValue();
  if (dirpar_check == "Direct"){
    
    copyofprodpricing.hideColumns(18,17);
  }
  else {
    copyofprodpricing.showColumns(18,17);
  }

  
  

  // Function to TOGGLE CELL
  var toggle1 = general_info.getRange("G2") 
  var toggle2 = product_Details.getRange("H2") 
  var toggle3 = op_Details.getRange("H2") 
  var toggle4 = marketplace.getRange("G2") 
  var toggle5 = approvals.getRange("G2") 
  var toggle6 = product_Pricing.getRange("K4") 
  var toggle7 = op_Pricing.getRange("G5") 
  var toggle8 = eos_EOL.getRange("G2") 
  var toggle9 = pac.getRange("I2") 
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      toggle1.setBackground("BLACK");
      // toggle1.setFontSize(12);
      toggle2.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle3.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle4.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle5.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle6.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle7.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle8.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle9.setBackground("BLACK");

    } 
    else {
      toggle1.setBackground("WHITE");
      // toggle1.setFontSize(10);
      toggle2.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle3.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle4.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle5.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle6.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle7.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle8.setBackground("WHITE");
      toggle9.setBackground("WHITE");

    } 
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
    Utilities.sleep(200); 
  }
}
```

Comment: About `I thought of using onEdit(e) trigger, but afraid it will adversely impact the working of other code blocks.`, I thought that if you cannot use the event object, the methods of `getActiveSheet` and `getActiveRange` of Class Spreadsheet might be able to be used. But, I think that your script is incomplete. For example, `general_info`, `pac_Detail`, `option_Details`, `option_Pricing` are not declared. By this, I cannot propose a modified script. So, I proposed a direction for modifying your actual script. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, I have update in the code my question

Comment: Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for testing your script?

Comment: I posted an answer that I consider may be useful for you. Let me know if that helps! @AliciaStone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the problem you are having with your current code is that the timestamp from cell A1 is being updated in each A1 from all the sheets at the same time and you want to make sure it gets updated only in the specific sheet where the change was made.

For this you can use the source value from the event object of the onEdit() trigger. This automatically reads the sheet where the change was made so you just need to get the range and set the values without having to read an each sheet, then the range, and then set the values individually.

Here is what you need to add to your code:

```js
//Add the event object e to your function
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  // Add this variable at the beginning
  var sourceSheet = e.source;


  // Replace the whole "Add timestamps" section of your code with this line
  sourceSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date);
}
```

#### How it works:

[image]

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)